# Divergence Gauss Theorem

Tags: integration, volume, gaussian-integral, divergence-operator

I am trying to compute the volume of a cell(the shape is hexagon prism but sometimes can be more than hexagon or less than hexagon) so I am trying to find a theorem that I can use to calculate the volume using the sides. I found this gauss theorem but in my case I do not know how to find the field vector(F). So is there any way to find the field vector? Moreover, in my case I do not know how to set the boundaries but I know the coordinates.

Also I am not pretty sure if there is any better theorem than works for me better.

Comment: It is not clear what your cell is ? If it is an hexagon prism the volume is just $\mathcal Ah$ where $\mathcal A$ is the area of the hexagon and $h$ the height of the prism. What do you mean by less or more than hexagon ? Is it pentagon, or heptagon ? Or do you mean it is still an hexagon but not a regular one with all equal sides ? Anyway, if it is still a prism the formula holds, only $\mathcal A$ changes. Please give some details. Is it a right prism, or is it leaning in that case formula changes too ?

Comment: Thank you for the replied! By more or less I mean heptagon or pentagon! Also it is a right prism without leaning! The problem that I have is how to apply the divergence gauss theorem to get the volume of the prism. Specifically I don't know what is the field of vector(F) and what boundaries I have to use for the integrals.